# R Date time conversion - lapply and unlist is converting to days after the epoch

Tags: r

I am converting a string for dates that look like `12/8/12`, probably in a rather roundabout way by 1) adding leading zeros (zero padding) to the day and month numbers and then converting to date object using the `as.Date` function in a custom function that I wrote.

```
date_conversion <-  function(date_string){
  split <- unlist(strsplit(date_string, "/"))  
  split[1] = str_pad(split[1], 2, pad = "0")
  split[2] = str_pad(split[1], 2, pad = "0")
  t = as.Date(paste(split, collapse = "/"),format='%m/%d/%y')
  return (t)
}
```

What's very confusing is that I can get back the result that I think I want when I call the function on one input:

```
> date_conversion(test[1])
[1] "2012-12-12"
> typeof(date_conversion(test[1]))
[1] "double"
```

Then when I use `lapply`, it returns this string representation:

```
    > lapply(test, date_conversion)
[[1]]
[1] "2012-12-12"

[[2]]
[1] "2015-12-12"

[[3]]
[1] "2015-09-09"
```

Then when I call `unlist`, the dates are changed into days since the epoch:

```
 unlist(lapply(test, date_conversion))
[1] 15686 16781 16687
```

I guess the underlying representation of the date is days since the epoch (hence `typeof` returns double, but why would the list value show the dates formatted in more human readable form and then calling `unlist` make them go to back to this days since the epoch form?

Also, is there a elegant way for me to do a conversion like this? Maybe I shouldn't be using Lapply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another solution with the `lubridate`package:

```
test <- c("12/8/12", "1/1/13", "2/4/13")

dates <- lubridate::mdy(test)
##[1] "2012-12-08" "2013-01-01" "2013-02-04"

class(dates)
##Date[1:3], format: "2012-12-08" "2013-01-01" "2013-02-04"

str(dates)
##[1] "Date"
```

The `lubridate` function `mdy()` converts the strings in your object `test` into month (m), days (d) and years (y). 
If your object `test` is a list, the same answer as aichao wrote, is possible with `lubridate::mdy((unlist(test))`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need your `date_conversion` function since `as.Date` will work with the format of your date strings, and it is vectorized. So, if `test` is a vector of your dates as strings:

```
test <- c("12/8/12", "1/1/13", "2/4/13")
print(result)
result <- as.Date(test, format="%m/%d/%y")
##[1] "2012-12-08" "2013-01-01" "2013-02-04"
str(result)
##Date[1:3], format: "2012-12-08" "2013-01-01" "2013-02-04"
class(result)
##[1] "Date"
```

If `test` is a `list`, then `unlist` first (i.e., `as.Date(unlist(test), format="%m/%d/%y")`).